Pandas: JSON Normalize a column with a list of dicts into columns
I've got a data file that consists of a whole bunch of JSON files being used as a relational database. Getting them into pandas is straightforward, but I'm trying to generate tabular reports that combine data from several columns and several dataframes. Each table row has an id field that is referenced by one or more cells in other tables, so I can do joins like I would in SQL.
However, some of those keys/ids are contained within nested JSON objects that are in individual cells. For instance, one column contains a list of dicts, and each of those dicts contains a pair of key:value pairs representing key:value tag metadata for the object in a give row of the dataframe. The first key:value pair is an id that references the tag key in a different table, the second key:value pair contains the actual value for the tag. So the end goal is to extract those key/value tags and put the values into a column named for the key. And I need to do this for as many tags as there are that exist, a number that is variable from one row to the next.
If I do a json normalize, it expands that list into columns in the dataframe that have numerical indices (corresponding to the list).
The incoming JSON looks like this:
deviceJSON = {
  "devices": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "noteIds": [],
      "vendor": "Aruba",
      "model": "2920F",
      "tags": [],
      "id": <guid>,
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "floor": <guid>,
        "coord": {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 200
        }
      },
      "name": "bar",
      "noteIds": ["32b60e81-8f9d-4ea2-9af0-8e441d31649b"],
      "vendor": "Cisco",
      "model": "6500",
      "tags": [
        {
          "tagKeyId": "68a9a2e4-9d03-42dd-8744-ed0d241f1746",
          "value": "IDF 1"
        },
        {
          "tagKeyId": "22a1adc4-bf73-4c52-a3f2-3bfca9d64011",
          "value": "e-Waste"
        }
      ],
      "id": <guid>,
    }
  ]
}

deviceDF=pd.DataFrame(deviceJSON['devices'])

So when importing this JSON into Pandas, tags (and noteIds, but that's beyond the scope of this question) is imported into a single column, and the contents of that column are the list contained within that dict.
What I ultimately need to get to is a column with the tag key either as tag_keyname or just keyname, and the values in that column (the keyname is in another Dataframe indexed by the tagKeyId):
tagKeysJSON = {
  "tagKeys": [
    {
      "key": "IDF",
      "id": "68a9a2e4-9d03-42dd-8744-ed0d241f1746",
    },
    {
      "key": "Disposition",
      "id": "22a1adc4-bf73-4c52-a3f2-3bfca9d64011",
    }
  ]
}

tagKeysDF=pd.DataFrame(tagKeysJSON['tagKeys'])

When I do this:
deviceDF=deviceDF.join(pd.json_normalize(deviceDF.tags))


I get columns labeled for the list index in tags that contain the dict:
Column 0:
{"tagKeyId": "68a9a2e4-9d03-42dd-8744-ed0d241f1746","value": "IDF 1"}

column 1:
{"tagKeyId": "22a1adc4-bf73-4c52-a3f2-3bfca9d64011","value": "e-Waste"}

Since the number of tags in the list can vary and they can be in any order, I can't really go and do another round of normalizing and keep the correct values with their respective keys, because another round of normalizing leaves me with columns of tagKeyId and value, rather than putting the value in a column for the relevant key.
I had previously done this, but it's deprecated and also inefficient:
tagsRawDF=deviceDF[['id','tags']]
tagsListDF=pd.DataFrame()
tagnameList=[]

for row in tagsRawDF.iterrows():
    taglist=row[1][1]
    df_dict={'deviceId' : row[1][0]}
    for tag in row[1][1]:
        tagrec=tagKeysDF.loc[tagKeysDF["id"]==tag['tagKeyId']]
        tagname='tag_'+tagrec.key.values[0].replace(" ","_")

        # Have we seen this tag name before? 
        # (this list is being built to be used later in the output phase)
        if tagname not in tagnameList : tagnameList.append(tagname) 

        df_dict[tagname]=tag['value']
    tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict, index=[0])

    tagsListDF = tagsListDF._append(tmp_df) # append the tmp_df to our final df

tagsListDF.reset_index(drop=True) 

deviceDF=pd.merge(deviceDF, tagsListDF, left_on='id', right_on='id',how='left')


The error message it gives is the usual:
FutureWarning: Series.getitem treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use ser.iloc[pos]
for tag in row[1][1]:
Which is oddly specific but simultaneously unhelpful, as I haven't been able to find any good documentation that explains how to refactor the code to use iloc instead.
So, I'm a little stuck on how to actually approach this - it would be straightforward if the number of tags was predictable, but this has now exceeded my limited knowledge of Pandas (and while the documentation is good, it doesn't help me if I don't know what I'm actually looking for).

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding that what you ultimately want to end up with. Given your deviceJSON, can you give a concrete example of how your final dataframe should look like?

import pandas as pd

# Input JSON data
deviceJSON = {
    "devices": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "noteIds": [],
            "vendor": "Aruba",
            "model": "2920F",
            "tags": [],
            "id": "device1",
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "floor": "floor1",
                "coord": {
                    "x": 100,
                    "y": 200
                }
            },
            "name": "bar",
            "noteIds": ["32b60e81-8f9d-4ea2-9af0-8e441d31649b"],
            "vendor": "Cisco",
            "model": "6500",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tagKeyId": "68a9a2e4-9d03-42dd-8744-ed0d241f1746",
                    "value": "IDF 1"
                },
                {
                    "tagKeyId": "22a1adc4-bf73-4c52-a3f2-3bfca9d64011",
                    "value": "e-Waste"
                }
            ],
            "id": "device2",
        }
    ]
}

tagKeysJSON = {
    "tagKeys": [
        {
            "key": "IDF",
            "id": "68a9a2e4-9d03-42dd-8744-ed0d241f1746",
        },
        {
            "key": "Disposition",
            "id": "22a1adc4-bf73-4c52-a3f2-3bfca9d64011",
        }
    ]
}

# Create DataFrames
deviceDF = pd.DataFrame(deviceJSON['devices'])
tagKeysDF = pd.DataFrame(tagKeysJSON['tagKeys'])

# Expand the tags column into multiple rows
tags_expanded = deviceDF.explode('tags')

# Extract tagKeyId and value from the tags column
tags_expanded['tagKeyId'] = tags_expanded['tags'].apply(lambda x: x['tagKeyId'] if isinstance(x, dict) else None)
tags_expanded['tagValue'] = tags_expanded['tags'].apply(lambda x: x['value'] if isinstance(x, dict) else None)

# Keep only the necessary columns
tags_expanded = tags_expanded[['id', 'tagKeyId', 'tagValue']]

# Merge with tagKeysDF to get tag names
merged_tags = pd.merge(tags_expanded, tagKeysDF, left_on='tagKeyId', right_on='id', how='left')

# Pivot to place tag values into columns named after the tags
pivot_tags = merged_tags.pivot(index='id', columns='key', values='tagValue')

# Merge back with the original deviceDF
final_df = deviceDF.merge(pivot_tags, on='id', how='left')

# Display the final result
print(final_df)

